# Clear list before asking for more data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a click listener in `recyclerview` on the basis of which I want the list to be updated . Like If I click on a button the list should be updated with the content ,and when the user clicks the button again, I want the data in the list to be empty and then fill it with the desired data. I am able to achieve the above without `childeventlistener` feature of `Firebase`, But by enabling `ChildEventListener`, I am finding difficult to implement the concept. 
The code is as follows.

**The Fragment is as follows**

```
The ViewModel which assigns data to the adapter
 viewModel.productdetail.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.adddetails(it)
        })


  // The onClickListener which on clicked gets data from Firebase
    override fun recyclerViewItemClickedHorizontal(view: View, text: String) {
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.card_hor -> {
                viewModel.productsdetails(text)
                viewModel.fetchtotal(text)

            }
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
   fun productsdetails(productname: String) {
    // I had tried to set the additems.clear here but it didn't work
        dbadd.child(productname).addChildEventListener(productchildlistener)
    }


    private val productchildlistener = object : ChildEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}

        override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {}

        override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
            val products = snapshot.getValue(AddModel::class.java)
            products?.id = snapshot.key
            _productdetail.value = products
        }

        override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
            val products = snapshot.getValue(AddModel::class.java)
            products?.id = snapshot.key
            _productdetail.value = products
        }

        override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

        }
    }
}
```

**The Adapter**

```
 private var additems = mutableListOf<AddModel>()


  // This functions assigns the data to the list
    fun adddetails(addmodel:AddModel) {


        additems.add(addmodel)
        notifyDataSetChanged()

    }
```

This is how I tried implementing it without CHILDEVENTLISTENER

```
      fun productsdetails(productname: String) {

          dbadd.child(productname).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
              override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}

              override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.exists()) {
                      val additems = mutableListOf<AddModel>()
                      additems.clear()
                      for (products in snapshot.children) {

                          val product = products.getValue(AddModel::class.java)
                          product?.id = products.key
                          product?.let { additems.add(it) }
                      }
                      _productdetail.value = additems

                  }
              }
          })

      }
```

While executing the above I had to assign the LiveData as >
and then supply the list to the adapter to do the needfull.
Thank-You for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you trigger

```
override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) { ... }
```

You already have your snapshot values to populate the list again, you can clear the list inside onChildChanged , read the new updated values, and send again that list to your adapter and notify the new data, this way you will always have fresh data in your list.

Comment: How it incremented it?

Comment: The list added the new data with the previous one.

Comment: Thank-you for your help.Further advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If it added the new data insode the cleared list you are not clearing the listo right , what did You use to clear tour list? It should be yourlist.clear()

Comment: Is there any particular method of calling the list ?